# Is it possible to have a mapped document as a nested object? [ElasticSearch]

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following document types defined in elasticSearch:

```
"token":{
    "properties":{
         "beginning":{"type": "string", "index":"not_analyzed", "doc_values":"true"},
         "end":{"type": "string", "index":"not_analyzed", "doc_values":"true"},
         "semantic_category":{"type": "string", "index":"not_analyzed", "doc_values":"true"},
    }    
}

"file":{
     "properties":{
         "abstract":{"type": "string", "index":"not_analyzed", "doc_values":"true"},
         "title":{"type": "string", "index":"not_analyzed", "doc_values":"true"},
    }    
}
```

I would like to have 2 nested Token objects in the "file" document, one being title_tokens and the other being abstract_tokens. However the only way I found is to define two different nested types.

Is there a way to include a document type as an object in a document?